# Is it possible that the line frequency can change along the distribution network?

Tags: electricity, distribution-network

We use single-phase 220-230V~/50Hz here in Turkey. The line frequency *may* vary ±5%.

One of my colleagues told me that he measured the line frequency in a factory (probably a customer's factory that we sold electricity meters) as **70Hz**.

I have nearly basic knowledge of electricity generators and distribution networks, but I think most of them could have identical (or nearly identical) specifications/properties. I know the line voltage can jump up to 240V or even 250V. But, how can the line frequency change? What can cause this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s not possible to tie different AC grids together unless they’re synchronized both in frequency and in phase.

Perhaps your friend is measuring a feed in his factory that has some harmonics on it kicked back from equipment? Or, they’re on a stand-alone system.

Answer (score 1):

3 phase motors can be fed with any frequency with the use of a variable frequency drive (VFD) unit to adjust the speed.

Or some kind of line harmonics.